# Electronic component which produces a clear clicking sound

Tags: sound

A surprisingly hard thing to search for as most references are to defects with other components.

Are there any such devices mass produced? or any good alternatives.

I've considered over-driving a relay and short spikes to a piezo but I'd doubt the life-span of the first and dislike the result from the second.

Comment: What about a speaker connected to your PC and a recording of a click? If not suitable please consider altering your question to rule out such ideas. One mans click is another man's tick is another man's tock etc. Maybe you need to define click better?

Comment: What about a relay? Not meant for it, but could do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a physical sound, a lot of projects, like [this one](http://www.klouche.com/knock-knock/), use a solenoid.  Another option would be a clock or metronome mechanism.  Otherwise, you're pretty much stuck with synthesizing or sampling a sound and outputting it through a speaker.

Comment: That's an option, probably the best, a lot of energy being wasted in what in unnecessary movement just to produce a click.